# xamarin.forms push notifications server side

Tags: push-notification, xamarin.forms

I implemented the .p12 Certificate for APN(Apple Push Notification) to my Windows Server.
Now I have an xamarin.forms App where i downloaded the Plugin.PushNotification.
I implemented in AppDelegate.cs RegisteredForRemoteNotifications, FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications and DidReceiveRemoteNotification Methods.

My question is, which Project (MVC, ASMX..) should I create on Server Side to send notifications to the Users who installed the App.

Furthermore I have an Portal programmed which is on this Server too. In this Portal I can send an message to the App too. But which Service do i Need ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No programming required at all :) Use https://onesignal.com for free, unlimited apps & notifications for iOS/Android + Web Push

Comment: But I want to write the Service for myself.

Comment: Well, then try PushSharp (C# library): https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp

Comment: Is pushsharp for sending notifications from Server to app and from Server to web application ? I cant read examples for this

Comment: Yes it is, read first sentence at https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp: "PushSharp is a server-side library for sending Push Notifications to iOS/OSX (APNS), Android/Chrome (GCM), Windows/Windows Phone, Amazon (ADM) and Blackberry devices!"

Comment: Ah okay, when I send an message from the web application, pushsharp is invoked, so that my webservice in iis with pushsharp send the notification to the users iPhone?
Is it right, that pushsharp works within an webservice ?

Comment: Is there a way to send from my iPhone to an webapi ?
Which Plugin do this Job?

Answer (score 0):

In my WebApp I used PushSharp to send Notifications to different devices.
In my App I use Plugin.PushNotification and it works like a charm.

Comment: can you share some resource of how this is done .. i need to push notifications from web app to Mobile app that uses xamarin forms

Answer (score 0):

using push sharp for sending push notifications through FCM

Comment: I  used PushSharp to send Notifications to different devices.